# JQuery: Wait till one GET request completed

Tags: jquery, wait, get-request

I need the application to wait till the first request is completed. The scenario is,

```
if (str != "") {
  if (str.match(",")) {
        var poolSequencedStatus = $.get("Request1.do"), function(response){
             //alert("Req1")
        }
  }

  $.get("Request2.do"), function(response){
     //alert("Req2")
  }
}
```

The Request2 should be called only after completing Request1 if the string contains the character ','.

Comment: call second .get in success of of first .get

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of promises and wrap it in a `$.when($.get("Request1.do")).then(function(){});`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 0):

Create a function of second request :

```
function GetRequest()
{

 $.get("Request2.do"), function(response){
     //alert("Req2")
  }

}
```

and call in the success of first:

```
if (str != "") {
  if (str.match(",")) {
        var poolSequencedStatus = $.get("Request1.do"), function(response){
             GetRequest();
        }
  }
```

Comment: If you want cleaner code, at least you could then get rid of the anonymous function wrapper and do `$.get( "Request1.do", GetRequest );`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str != "") {
  if (str.match(",")) {
        var poolSequencedStatus = $.get("Request1.do"), function(response){
             //alert("Req1");
           $.get("Request2.do"), function(response){
     //alert("Req2")
           }
        }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Jquery works on sync mode.

Check the value of async:false of your $.ajax settings.

Otherwise, you can use the benefit of $.when() in your latest jQuery.

```
    // Using the $.when() method, we can create an object that behaves similarly
// to Deferred objects, but for COMBINATIONS of Deferred objects.
//
// The $.when() method creates a Deferred object that is resolved or rejected
// when all the Deferred objects passed into it are resolved or rejected.
var getPromise = function(name) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  setTimeout(function() { dfd.resolve(name + ": " + num); }, num);
  return dfd.promise();
};

var list = $("<ul/>").appendTo($("#target").empty());
var printLine = function(str) {
  $("<li class=well/>").html(str).appendTo(list);
};

// Each of these Promises will individually print when resolved.
var promiseA = getPromise("A").done(printLine);
var promiseB = getPromise("B").done(printLine);
var promiseC = getPromise("C").done(printLine);

// And this code will execute once all Promises have resolved.
$.when(promiseA, promiseB, promiseC).then(function(numA, numB, numC) {
  printLine(numA + ", " + numB + ", " + numC);
});
```